# iPhone: Decode characters like \U05de

Tags: json, encoding, ios4, decoding, hebrew

I used SBJsonParser to parse a json string.
inside, instead of hebrew chars, I got a string full of chars in a form like \U05de
what would be the best way to decode these back to hebrew chars,
so i can put these on controls like UIFieldView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I ran a loop iterating in the string for the chars \u
in the loop, when detected such a substring, i took a range of 6 characters since that index,
giving me a substring for example \u052v that need to be fixed.
on this string, i ran the method `[str JSONValue]`, which gave me the correct char, then i simply replaced all occurrences of \u052v (for example) with the latter corrected char.